# Objective-C: Catch object deallocation

Tags: objective-c, hook, dealloc

I work with object not from my library (let's call this object EAGLContext). I want to attach my object (let's call it ShaderManager) to EAGLContext. ShaderManager should be deallocated when EAGLContext is going to be deallocated. Important thing here is that I need instance of EAGLContext inside of ShaderManager's dealloc.

Unfortunately I can't use association mechanism, because (as I understand) release of ShaderManager will happen after EAGLContext is deallocated.

So the question is: how to catch event "3rd party object will be deallocated"?

Comment: Create a subclass of EAGLContext and hook it's dealloc.

Comment: I don't allocate/initialize instance of EAGLContext, so I can't replace it by derived class.

Comment: Then you can always retain the object (or keep in `strong` pointer) so that it doesn't get deallocated until you say so.

Comment: I don't have strong pointer to EAGLContext because I don't want control lifetime of this object.